# How to remove GMSPolygon from GMSMapView

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

Does exist any way to remove GMSPolygons from GMSMapView?

It does not seem to exist a property of GMSMapView containing them (as GMSPlolyLines), should I clear the map and render all again?

thanks

Comment: Check my code for do it in this topic.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25102778/remove-gmspolyline-from-gmsmapview/30364285#30364285

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When you create the `GMSPolygon` you set its `map` property to add it to the map. To remove it from the map, set its `map` property to `nil`. This means you need to keep your own record of the polygons which you've added to the map, which you want to be able to remove later.

For example `mySavedPolygon.map = nil`

Comment: thanks saxon, works for me. once I've seen the solution I've also seen it's obvious, but I'm new at ios and google maps ios sdk

Answer (score 6):

From [google maps document](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/interface_g_m_s_map_view)

> - clear Clears all markup that has been added to the map, including markers, polylines and ground overlays.

So you just use

```
[mapView clear];
```

This should clear the polygons.

Comment: @Bangalore please refer to the newest google maps documentation. This answer is almost 3 year old, and may not work in the latest SDK.

Comment: checkout my issue, i think [map clear ] is the correct answer but some how its not working for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36114766/gmsmapview-clear-method-is-not-removing-gmspolygon-ios/36122085#36122085

Comment: @Bangalore You management solve the problem ? I am use the viewMap.clear and viewMap.map = nil but this no work.

Answer (score 2):

This has been updated, has I am using the clear function, and was looking for a **way to keep the polygons** while using this.

I've just **confirmed against** the Google Maps API Reference.

> Clears all markup that has been added to the map, including markers, polylines and ground overlays.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_map_view.html#a28e6b8aeb7c8dc9025dc001f2a5d2c9b