# Remove GMSPolyline from GMSMapView

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am using GoogleMap-IOS-1.8.1 SDK for displaying a map. I have to draw a GMSPolyline on the map. After a particular event I have to remove all GMSPolyline paths except for markers.  I'm not sure of the best way to do that.
The GoogleMaps documentation for iOS describe two methods to sue.

```
 1. [mapView_ clear];
 2. Set the GMSPolyline map property to nil
```

Here the first approach removes all Markers and Overlays as well. This isn't exactly what I want.
   And for 2nd one it doesn't seem like the best method to save all of the GMSPolyline object references and then go back and set them all to nil.

Is there a better way to do accomplish this task, or is this the only proper / correct way to do this?

I was hoping for something like the following.

```
for (GMSPolyline *polylineToremove  in mapView_.polyline)
{
    [mapView_ removeOverlay:overlayToRemove];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You do need to do as you've said - store a reference to all of the polylines you've added (eg in an array), and then loop over them and set their `map` property to nil.

Comment: Actually i want to skip reference part. i don't want store reference if there is another way. There should be some property of MapView thorough which we can get all Type of overLay.

Comment: No, there isn't. There used to be, but you can see in the release notes at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/releases that Google removed this in version 1.7. Now the recommended approach is to maintain your own reference of what you've added, if you want to be able to delete it later.

Answer (score 4):

You just need to set GMSPolyline map property to nil.

```
GMSPolyline *polyline;
polyline.map = nil;
```

Comment: how do i get it back?

Comment: If i have a lot of polylines, How can i remove just one of them?

Comment: @Robert a bit late but to remove just a single one idea is to create a dictionary and assign a single polyline to the dictionary and then use the key of the dictionary to reference the polyline you want to remove.

Answer (score 2):

Just use below properly of Google Map:

```
mapView.clear()
```

Clears all markup that has been added to the map, including markers, polylines and ground

Comment: above line clear mapview, due to that all markers with polyline also remove.
when you want to remove all things like marker and polylline then clear map. And when you have to clear polyline then use below code

polyline.map = nil

Comment: @RahulFate Yes this line will clear all polylines on map. What you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

This is code you need to remove any overlayView from GMSMapView.
You can also do it with GMSMarkers, GMSPolyline.

```
for (GMSPolyline *polylineToRemove  in arrPolylineAdded){
      polylineToRemove.map = nil;
      polylineToRemove     = nil;
}
```

I have just checked :) for Google Map SDK Version 1.9.2.

Comment: Fast enumeration variables can't be modified in ARC, by default. This doesn't work.

Comment: And how about GMSMarker?, I checked with GMSMarker and I guess that GMSPolyline is the same. I am sorry about it.

Comment: I'm saying that       polylineToRemove = nil;    in this case is impossible

Answer (score -1):

Using Swift 3;
Using this function first remove all polyline

```
   import GoogleMaps
    
   var polylineArray = [GMSPolyline]()    

   override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
    for root: GMSPolyline in self.polylineArray
      {
        if root.userData as! String == "root"
        {
           root.map = nil
           }
      }
   }
```

then drow again the polyline

```
func showPath(polyStr :String)
{
    let path = GMSPath(fromEncodedPath: polyStr)
    DispatchQueue.main.async 
    {
        let polyline = GMSPolyline(path: path)
        //MARK: remove the old polyline from the GoogleMap
        for root: GMSPolyline in self.polylineArray {
            if root.userData as! String == "root" {
               root.map = nil
            }
        }
        polyline.strokeWidth = 2.0
        polyline.strokeColor = sDefaultViewColorPrimaryDark
        polyline.userData = "root"
        polyline.map = self.mapView
        let bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds(path: path!)
        self.mapView!.animate(with: GMSCameraUpdate.fit(bounds,withPadding: 15.0))
        self.polylineArray.append(polyline)
        //self.mapView!.moveCamera(update)
    }
}
```