# Remove only polylines from GMSMapView without reference of them

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, swift3, gmsmapview

How to remove only the polylines from my GMSMapView in Swift.

I don't use `map.clear()` because I have like 100 markers and groundOverlays that I don't want to delete and I do not have references of them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove GMSPolyline from GMSMapView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25102778/remove-gmspolyline-from-gmsmapview)

Comment: @the4kman it is not a duplicate, because that question is of Objective-C code and do not have an accepted answer. Also I edited my question to show the difference of my question. Because y do not have reference of the polylines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep a record of the Polyline Array and set the .map property to nil for each polyline you want to remove.

```
let poly = GSMPolyline()

poly.map = mapView to show

poly.map = nil to remove
```

Comment: I have already implemented that solution, but I was wondering if there was already a mapview function for that