# GMSMapView clear method is not removing GMSPolygon iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have add Polygons in google map using below codes

```
  for(int i = 0; i < [[polygon  valueForKey:@"coordinates"] count]; i++){

         [self.path addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([[[[polygon  valueForKey:@"coordinates"] objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:1] floatValue],[[[[polygon  valueForKey:@"coordinates"] objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:0] floatValue])];
     }

     GMSPolygon *rectangle = [GMSPolygon polygonWithPath:self.path];
      rectangle.fillColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0/255.0 green:0.0/255.0 blue:0.0/255.0 alpha:0.4];
      rectangle.map = self.mapView;
      rectangle.strokeColor=[UIColor redColor];
      [self.restrictedLocations addObject:rectangle];


      CLLocation *userLocation = [[mymanager sharedManager] userLocation];

        [self.mapView bringSubviewToFront:self.locationMarkerView];
        GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:userLocation.coordinate.latitude
                                                                longitude:userLocation.coordinate.longitude
                                                                     zoom:7];
  self.mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
```

I can see polygon in my map and i added following code to remove Polygon from map .

```
[self.mapView clear];
```

and this is not working, i can still see polygon in google map .

Please help me

```
UPDATE

My GSMMapView is not programmatically created , actually added one UIView and changed its class to GSMMApView. is that the issue ?
```

When i added log and run this adding polygon method,
So i got following values

First time i can see polygons on map and that time my log

```
NSLog(@"%@",[mapView description]);
```

shows like this

```
<GMSMapView: 0x1610eb760; frame = (0 0; 320 504); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x16127e4f0>; layer = <GMSMapLayer: 0x1610ebc10>>
```

Then i  tried to run `[mapView clear]` and its not working so i got log for that also

second time  my log

```
NSLog(@"%@",[mapView description]);
```

shows like this

```
<GMSMapView: 0x15ff9c550; frame = (0 0; 0 0); clipsToBounds = YES; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x162340e30>; layer = <GMSMapLayer: 0x15ffca4b0>>
```

Comment: possible duplicate. Kindly refer to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17601408/how-to-remove-gmspolygon-from-gmsmapview?rq=1

Comment: if its working i wont post again

Comment: have you tried setting its .map property to nil?

Comment: yes, then polygons will go but later am not able to add polygon again

Comment: @Mr.Rebot please check my updated question

Comment: @Mr.Rebot pls take a look

Comment: @Bangalore did you find answer?